# Java Kafka Consumer Processing Binary Image Data

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka and currently have a need to extract binary image data.  I'm currently using a KafkaAvroDeserializer. The key and values of the ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> is:

```
Key {"prim_key": -99999999, "seq": 1} 
value {"beforeImage": null, "afterImage": {"prim_key": -99999999, "seq": 1, "bin_data": {"bytes": ..................}}}
```

How can I extract the "bytes" raw byte data?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Avro Deserializer, then you wouldn't use byte arrays as the record types, you could use `ConsumerRecord<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>`, then extract out the appropriate field from the data

Otherwise, if you only needed byte arrays, the producer would use the ByteArraySerializer which wouldn't be compatible with the Avro Deserializer

Comment: I'm able to retrieve the binary (byte[]) data from the  ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> consumerRecord = (ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]>) record.getConsumerRecord();  consumerRecord.value();  I have not been able to determine the beginning and end of the "bytes" data.

Comment: According to your post, your bytes are within some `"bin_data"`object, inside `"after_image"` which is inside of an Avro object. Therefore, don't use a record of bytes